# Data found in PE full image but not in segment?

Tags: python, c, x86, shellcode

I have below C program which is compiled to binary:

bin.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    unsigned char buf[] = "\xfc\xe8\x82\x00\x00\x00";

    printf("Shellcode Length:  %d\n", strlen(buf));
    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())buf;
    ret();

    return 0;
}
```

Once I have this compiled into bin.exe, I am trying to search that which segment of the program while disassembling contains the `buf[]` data (I was expecting that it would be in `.data` segment but it is not).

In order to search the bytes I am using python pefile as following:

pefile output:

```
if(b"\xfc\xe8\x82" in exe.get_memory_mapped_image()):
     print("Shell found in image dump")

for sec in exe.sections:
    print(sec.PointerToRawData, sec.SizeOfRawData)
    sectionData = sec.get_data(sec.PointerToRawData, sec.SizeOfRawData)
    if (b"\xfc\xe8\x82" in sectionData):
        print("Shell found in section dump")
        print(sec.Name)
```

Console output:

```
Shell found in image dump
(1536, 7680)
(9216, 512)
(9728, 2560)
(12288, 1024)
(13312, 512)
(0, 0)
(13824, 2048)
(15872, 512)
(16384, 512)
(16896, 1024)
(17920, 200192)
(218112, 8704)
(226816, 10752)
(237568, 2560)
(240128, 1536)
(241664, 11264)
(252928, 1024)
```

as you can see, the full image is able to find the `buf` bytes, but neither of the segments contain the `buf`.

Can anyone explain what am I missing here? or why do never get to find the specific segment that holds the bin.exe's buf data?

Answer (score 1):

It is not stored at all (at least not as ann array).

If you do not optimize the stack variable will be initialized by the immediate store instructions by most modern implementations:

```
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-15], 8579324  <- hewre is your code
        mov     WORD PTR [rbp-11], 0
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-9], 0
```

If you enable optimizations the stack variable will not be initialized at all.

```
main:
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     esi, 3
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        lea     rdx, [rsp+9]
        xor     eax, eax
        call    rdx
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
```

To prevent it you need to make it static:

```
int main(){
    static unsigned char buf[] = "\xfc\xe8\x82\x00\x00\x00";

    printf("Shellcode Length:  %d\n", strlen(buf));
    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())buf;
    ret();

    return 0;
}
```

And the code:

```
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:buf.0
        call    strlen
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     rsi, rax
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        call    buf.0
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
buf.0:
        .string "\374\350\202"
        .string ""
        .string ""
        .string ""
```

But of course you cant execute it on any modern OS as you do not have executable rights to this memory area.

Comment: but it still need to be under .text/.code segment right? as it afterward will be pushed to stack

Comment: No, onr is direct instruction, in second it does not exist at all.